# How to interpret the contents of a replication slot state file in the data directory

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.6, master-slave-replication

We know that there is a **state file** for slot in the `data/pg_replslot/<slot_name>` directory.
It is needed when server restarts after a crash.

Questions:

1. How is the data stored inside this state file? If data are flushed from memory, in what exact format?
2. How to read the contents of this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the definitions in `src/backend/replication/slot.c` and `src/backend/replication/slot.h`:

```c
/*
 * Replication slot on-disk data structure.
 */
typedef struct ReplicationSlotOnDisk
{
    /* first part of this struct needs to be version independent */

    /* data not covered by checksum */
    uint32      magic;
    pg_crc32c   checksum;

    /* data covered by checksum */
    uint32      version;
    uint32      length;

    /*
     * The actual data in the slot that follows can differ based on the above
     * 'version'.
     */

    ReplicationSlotPersistentData slotdata;
} ReplicationSlotOnDisk;
```

```c
/*
 * On-Disk data of a replication slot, preserved across restarts.
 */
typedef struct ReplicationSlotPersistentData
{
    /* The slot's identifier */
    NameData    name;

    /* database the slot is active on */
    Oid         database;

    /*
     * The slot's behaviour when being dropped (or restored after a crash).
     */
    ReplicationSlotPersistency persistency;

    /*
     * xmin horizon for data
     *
     * NB: This may represent a value that hasn't been written to disk yet;
     * see notes for effective_xmin, below.
     */
    TransactionId xmin;

    /*
     * xmin horizon for catalog tuples
     *
     * NB: This may represent a value that hasn't been written to disk yet;
     * see notes for effective_xmin, below.
     */
    TransactionId catalog_xmin;

    /* oldest LSN that might be required by this replication slot */
    XLogRecPtr  restart_lsn;

    /* RS_INVAL_NONE if valid, or the reason for having been invalidated */
    ReplicationSlotInvalidationCause invalidated;

    /*
     * Oldest LSN that the client has acked receipt for.  This is used as the
     * start_lsn point in case the client doesn't specify one, and also as a
     * safety measure to jump forwards in case the client specifies a
     * start_lsn that's further in the past than this value.
     */
    XLogRecPtr  confirmed_flush;

    /*
     * LSN at which we enabled two_phase commit for this slot or LSN at which
     * we found a consistent point at the time of slot creation.
     */
    XLogRecPtr  two_phase_at;

    /*
     * Allow decoding of prepared transactions?
     */
    bool        two_phase;

    /* plugin name */
    NameData    plugin;
} ReplicationSlotPersistentData;
```